# How to set grid (vector or arrows) lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

The location of the grid lines (parallel to Y-axis) at X-axis are defined at third row of a files, for example.

The third lines has the points

```
#   0.00000000 0.08329780 0.11683890 0.20013670 0.23367770
```

I can get the Ymax from another file defined as FILE with

```
set table $Dummy
plot FILE u ($0==1?(Ymax=$2): NaN) w table # i have updated this line. This will be used only for height of the grid line. Here FILE is a data file with two columns only which will be plotted in X-Y format.

unset table
```

How I can set grid lines at above locations that should end to Ymax ?

I need something like:

```
for i in 0.00000000 0.08329780 0.11683890 0.20013670 0.23367770
do
set arrow $i, Ymax lc rgb "black" dt 2 nohead 
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ethan already pointed out, gridlines are bound to major or minor tics and span the whole graph.
But you can plot something `with vectors`.

By the way, note that with your code

```
set table $Dummy
    plot FILE u ($0==1?(Ymin=$1,Ymax=$2):NaN,Xmax=$8) w table
unset table
```

`Ymin` and `Ymax` will be the values of of the first and second column of the second line(row) of the *last* dataset. If your data has no empty lines then the last dataset is also the first. `Xmax` will be the overall last value of the 8th column.

For you task, one solution could be the following below. No need for sed or awk, etc.
Since I don't have example data from you I assume something.

1. get the x positions for your "grid lines" from one datafile
2. extract `Ymin,Ymax,Xmax` from another datafile
3. plot your data `with linespoints` and the "grid lines" `with vectors`

Note that in earlier gnuplot versions there was a limitation of `strcol()` to (I guess) 63 characters. With gnuplot 5.2.7 this has been fixed.

**Code:**

```
### use vector plot to plot "grid lines"
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
# first line
# second line
# 0.00000000 0.08329780 0.11683890 0.20013670 0.23367770
# below this line data starts
1  4
2  5
3  6
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
1.1  2.7  0  0  1.2  0  0  0.00
1.2  2.6  0  0  1.8  0  0  0.05
1.3  2.5  0  0  2.5  0  0  0.10
1.4  2.4  0  0  2.1  0  0  0.15
1.5  2.3  0  0  1.6  0  0  0.17
1.6  2.2  0  0  1.7  0  0  0.20
1.7  2.1  0  0  2.4  0  0  0.25
EOD

set table $Dummy
    set datafile commentschars ''       # all lines will be data line
    set datafile separator '\n'         # in order to get full lines
    plot $Data1 u (xValues = strcol(1)) index 0 every ::2::2 w table   # get the complete 3rd line
    set datafile commentschars '#'      # reset the comment character
    set datafile separator whitespace   # reset the column separator
    plot t=0 $Data2 u (t==0?(Ymin=$1,Ymax=$2,t=1):NaN,Xmax=$8) w table  # get Ymin,Ymax,Xmax
unset table
print Ymin, Ymax, Xmax, xValues

xValue(n) = real(word(xValues,n+1))   # function to extract xValue

set xrange[-0.05:0.3]
set samples words(xValues)-1    # set number of datapoints of special datafile '+'

plot '+' u (xValue(int($0+1))):(Ymin):(0):(Ymax-Ymin) w vectors lc rgb "black" dt 2 nohead not, \
     $Data2 u 8:5 w lp pt 7 lc rgb "red" title "Data"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

Above I've shown you how to extract the necessary values with gnuplot.
Yes, that's not so easy to understand and not the shortest way, but it's *gnuplot only*! If you prefer to use sed, awk or the like feel free, but there I cannot help.

Another approach instead of plotting vectors is drawing arrows. The assumption is that you have your data in your variables already.

**Code:**

```
### draw arrows from a data string
reset session

xValues = "0.00000000 0.08329780 0.11683890 0.20013670 0.23367770"

Ymin = 0.2
Ymax = 0.9
Xmax = 0.25

i=0
do for [xValue in xValues] {
    i=i+1
    set arrow i from xValue,Ymin to xValue,Ymax nohead dt 2
}

set xrange[-0.05:0.4]
set yrange[0:1]

plot x
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Can I grep xValues from my data file directly? On terminal I can get them as: head -n 3 332.dat  | tail -n 1 |  tr -d '#'

Comment: Like something xValues = "(head -n 3 332.dat  | tail -n 1 |  tr -d '#')"

Comment: glad that it finally worked out. If the answer is acceptable, please mark it as such and your question will appear as answered.

Comment: Sir, any solution for the other comment?

Comment: about grepping data from the datafile "directly"? Sorry, I don't know sed, awk or other Unix utilities.

Comment: Yes, I want to grep data directly from the file.

Answer (score 1):

Grid lines are placed at axis tick locations.  The major ticks (tick level 0) and minor ticks (tick level 1) are tracked separately.  The linetype of the grid lines can also be chosen. To generate thin blue vertical grid lines at the x coordinates you show using minor ticks to control the grid lines:

```
  set xtics add ( 0.00000000 1, 0.08329780 1, 0.11683890 1, 0.20013670 1, 0.23367770 1 )
  set grid mx lt 0, lt 1 lw 0.5 lc "blue"
```

As always see the documentation (help set xtics, help set grid) for more details.

Comment: This does not help me.

Comment: There should be some script (that can be used in gnuplot) in such a way that it automatically collect the grid line locations and it should show grid line on each location upto Ymax (Ymax is defined in  in my original post).

Comment: Grid lines always span the full height or width of the plot