# How to set grid/vector/arrow lines at the particular locations and that location has to be pointed out from a command

Tags: gnuplot

I am updating my previous question which is posted here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62093555/how-to-set-grid-lines-in-gnuplot/62094090?noredirect=1#comment109823515_62094090
```

I have a file case.dat ( top three lines is mentioned below) which has grid locations (to be drawn from X($i to Ymax ; where $i will take data one by one from equation 2) and I can grep them on terminal using

```
head -n 3 case.dat  | tail -n 1 | sed -n -e 's/#//p' | tr -s ' '   (1)
```

The above command will result in the locations of the grid lines at X-axis (these locations will change case by case)

```
 0.00000000 0.08329780 0.11683890 0.20013670 0.23367770    (2)
```

In gnuplot script I can fix the Ymax using

```
set table $Dummy
plot FILE u ($0==1?(Ymax=$2): NaN) w table # i have updated this line. This will be used only for height of the grid line. Here FILE is a data file with two coloum only which will be plotted in X-Y format.

unset table                   (1)
```

I want to update my gnuplot script such that the first command (heas -n 3 ...) should work in the gnuplot script and then  it, along with command second (set table ...), should automatically set grid lines as per these two commands.

I need something like:

```
for i in 0.00000000 0.08329780 0.11683890 0.20013670 0.23367770
do
set arrow $i, Ymax lc rgb "black" dt 2 nohead 
done
```

The head of the case.dat is this

```
# distance  frequency
# End points of segments: 
#   0.00000000 0.08329780 0.11683890 0.20013670 0.23367770       (4)
```

Comment: I guess this question is now obsolete. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62108274/7295599 no need for sed, awk, etc...

Comment: Thank you theozh for your help but it did not work for me. I found your code much complex. Yes, I want dashed lines what you did in your code. But there should be something much more simple that all should do in gnuplot file. I want to spacify only name of data file that is here "case.dat" and then equation (1) and (3) should do automatic.

Comment: This post is more clear. In my old post I did not defined the question properly.

Comment: @astha Pease edit and update your first question appropriately. There is no need to spread your I formation over three questions

Comment: Okay Sir, I go the point